# Google Playデベロッパー ポリシー違反に関わる警告について

Tags: android, google-play-service

初めまして。 
最近アプリを作り始め、Google Play にUPできるようになりました。 
その後、Googleより下記の警告がありました。

> 警告の詳細: Google Play
>   では、ユーザーや端末に関する機密情報を要求する、または取り扱うアプリの場合、デベロッパーは有効なプライバシー
>   ポリシーを提供する必要があります。当該のアプリは、個人情報または機密情報に関わる権限
>   （カメラ、マイク、アカウント、連絡先、スマートフォンなど） またはユーザー データを要求していますが、有効なプライバシー
>   ポリシーが確認できませんでした。

上記の様な仕様にしているつもりはなく、UPした権限を確認してみたところ、 
下記の内容になっていました。

```
android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE 
android.permission.INTERNET 
android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE 
android.permission.WAKE_LOCK 
com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE 
net.box_i.shinya.tasuhiku_apuri.permission.C2D_MESSAGE
```

アプリにはデータベース接続と、AdMobの広告を使用しています。 
3行目以外は、それらのための権限と思っています。 
気になる3行目は、前に一度、ゲームアクセス数を確認 
するため、スマホIDを取得しようとしたことがありました。 
今はID取得はしようとしていませんが、その名残でしょうか？ 
自分で記入した記憶はありません。
開発ではandroid studioをしようしています。
「android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE」 
この権限を削除すれば、他に何もしなくても、違反にはならないでしょうか？ 
それとも、何かの表示等が必要でしょうか？

分からず困っております。 
申し訳ございませんが、よろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: マルチポスト　https://teratail.com/questions/64986

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Permissionに関しては
ソースコード上実際に端末にアクセスしているかどうか、
ではなく
Manifest上その権限を使用宣言しているかどうか。

で判断されます。

ですので
android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE
を現在必要ないのであれば削除すべきです。

また、PrivacyPolicyが要求されるのは(恐らくがついてしまいますが)
Dangerous Permission以上のレベルのPermissionに関してだと思います。
https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/permissions/requesting.html
(「以上」とつけていますが、一般アプリはDangerousPermissionより強いPermissionは使用不可ですので、
Dangerous Permissionだけ気をつけていただければ良いと思います。)

上記の中にはDangerous PermissionはREAD_PHONE_STATEだけのようですので、
該当Permissionを削除することで警告は来なくなるとは思います。

---

下記のページで列記される情報収集を行うようなアプリは基本的にプライバシーポリシーは入力が必須となっておりますとの記載があります。
https://play.google.com/intl/ja_ALL/about/privacy-security/additional-requirements/

> ユーザーの個人情報や機密情報（個人識別情報、財務情報、支払い情報、認証情報、電話帳や連絡先のデータ、マイクやカメラのセンサーデータ、端末の機密情報など）

こちらの情報は基本的にDangerousPermissionがないと取得できない情報となりますので、
やはり「Dangerous Permissionを使う場合はプライバシーポリシーが必要」といえますが、
DangerousPermissionの有無に関わらず、判断に困る場合はプライバシーポリシーを用意したほうが無難かと思います。

Comment: 早速のご回答ありがとうございます。Dangerous Permissionに気を付けた方が良いということで、とりあえず早速、READ_PHONE_STATEについては削除します。また、プライバシーポリシーの対応についても考えたいと思います。※マルチポストがマナー違反とはしりませんでした。申し訳ございません。

Comment: マルチポストそのものがマナー違反かどうかは微妙なところですが、少なくともマルチポスト先の回答をスタックオーバーフロー側に反映しないのはマナー違反であるという見解のようです。・・・ということでマルチポスト先の回答を私の回答に反映しておきました。問題なければチェックマーク✔を押して本質問を終了させてください。

Comment: teratailの回答は「如何なる場合もプライバシーポリシーは必須」となっていたのですが、Googleのドキュメント上は「該当情報を扱う場合のみ」となっており、「該当情報」はDangerousPermissionで取得できる情報と一致していたので、「いかなる場合でも必須」とは言えず、表現を「用意したほうが無難」に変更しました。

Comment: @ema マルチポストについてはこちらもご覧ください: http://meta.ja.stackoverflow.com/a/2250/8000 禁止するわけではありませんが、他の回答者やあとから読んだ人のためにも、せめてマルチポスト先ぐらいは書いてほしいという感じです。teratailでも同様の案内がヘルプに書かれています: https://teratail.com/help